# How To get the success/failure response after sending mandatory parameters in PayuMoney integration using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am Developing E-commerce Application using angular and node. While Integrating the PayuMoney. i got Some problem. After Sending the all the Mandatory Parameters 
the page redirect to payment gateway And After Success/failure the payment  the page redirect automatically surl/furl.

My Problem is After Success Redirection done how  i will call the order post method.

Html code:

```
<form action="https://secure.payu.in/_payment" method="post">
<input type="text" ng-model="paymentdata.txnid"  name="txnid"      class="hidden">
<input type="text" ng-model="paymentdata.key"  name="key" class="hidden">
<input type="text" ng-model="paymentdata.amount"  name="amount" class="hidden">       
<input type="text" ng-model="paymentdata.productinfo"  name="productinfo" class="hidden">
<input type="text" ng-model="paymentdata.firstname" name="firstname" class="hidden">
<input type="text" ng-model="paymentdata.email"  name="email" class="hidden">
<input type="text" ng-model="paymentdata.phone"  name="phone" class="hidden">         
<input type="text" ng-model="paymentdata.hash" name="hash" class="hidden">
<input type="text" ng-model="paymentdata.surl"  name="surl" class="hidden">
<input type="text" ng-model="paymentdata.furl"  name="furl" class="hidden">
<input type="text" ng-model="paymentdata.service_provider"  name="service_provider" class="hidden">
<button class="button style-10" href="" ng-click="ProceedToCheckout(checkout)" type="submit" value="submit">Checkout</button>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.ProceedToCheckout=function(checkout){
  // checkout is my order information
  $http.post("http://nodejs-restpos.rhcloud.com",checkout).success(function(data){
         console.log(data)
     }).error(function(data){
         console.log(data)
     })
```

Post method done after the payment gateway success. please tell me how to get response of payment gateway. After getting the response the order data will be posted.

Comment: Were you able to find an answer to this problem?